Proving Cosine Addition Identity using Complex numbers
I want to see how one can stumble upon the following using complex numbers
$\cos{A} + \cos{B} = 2\cos{\frac{A+B}{2}}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}$
I know getting to angle sum formulas like $\cos{(A+B)}$ and $\sin{(A+B)}$ is easy. Just sub in $(A+B)$ as the angle in Euler's formula.
I know the $\cos{A} + \cos{B}$ formula can be derived by letting $A+B=C$, $A-B=D$, bringing the question into a $\cos{(C+D)} + \cos{(C-D)}$ format and then cancelling out a few terms, you get the formula.
But is there an elegant way to reach it? Using exponential rules and Euler's formula in a very elegant way... I mean something that doesn't require the thought, "Oh let me write it as a sum and difference". Something more straightforward... something that would be a very natural thing to do. For someone who doesn't know the answer in the first place.
EDIT:
I'm not talking about a way up the answer to the question. Just a naive travel to the answer itself as if it is unknown. So I'm NOT looking for a way that starts with defining 2cos((A+B)/2)cos((A-B)/2) and works its way up. Rather, the other way around.

If you have the occasion to edit, could you please re-tag "complex-geometry" (which this is not ;) to "geometry"?

Generalizing the usual trick to find the modulus and argument of $e^{ia}+1$, let us divide $e^{iA}+e^{iB}$ by $e^{i\frac{A+B}2}$. The quotient is $e^{i\frac{2A-(A+B)}2}+e^{i\frac{2B-(A+B)}2}$. Then, taking the real and imaginary parts of
$$e^{iA}+e^{iB}=e^{i\frac{A+B}2}\left(e^{i\frac{A-B}2}+e^{i\frac{B-A}2}\right)=2e^{i\frac{A+B}2}\cos\frac{A-B}2$$
we get simultaneously
$$\begin{cases}\cos A+\cos B&=2\cos\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2,\\
\sin A+\sin B&=2\sin\frac{A+B}2\cos\frac{A-B}2.
\end{cases}$$

Oh well, that's working from the answer up to the question... I'm sorry I didn't clarify it in the first place... I'm looking for a naive approach for someone who doesn't know the answer in the first place... How would we reach the answer?

Does my updated answer still not suit you?

Oh yeah! This works! A little clarity on the step... perhaps how it's just A = 2A/2 = (2A + B - B)/2 would be nice!
Although this is kinda tough to come up with on your own if you don't have a hint of what the answer might look like, this is sure really elegant! Thank you!
